# html2Canvas unable to retrieve the data url in time for pdf generation

Tags: javascript, callback, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I need help with assigning the data url I get from the html2canvas promise to the listingReportImg in the downloadPdf() function.

**Expected Result:**

```
listingReportImg = data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg ...
```

**Logs**

```
listingReportImg::  undefined

listing report uri:: 
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg ...
```

**listings.component.html**

```
<button (click)="downloadPdf()">Print</button>
```

**listings.component.ts**

```
listingReportToDataUrl(){
    let listingReport = document.getElementById('listing-report');
    console.log("listingReport:: ", listingReport);
    html2canvas( listingReport, { useCORS: true } )
        .then(function (canvas) {
            let listingReportUri = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            console.log("listing report uri::", listingReportUri);
            return listingReportUri;
        });
}

downloadPdf(){
    let listingReportImg = this.listingReportToDataUrl();
    console.log("listingReportImg:: ", listingReportImg);
    pdfMake.createPdf(listingReport( listingReportImg )).download('test.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having returned from your callbacks properly,

```
listingReportToDataUrl(){
            const listingReport = document.getElementById('listing-report')
            return html2canvas( listingReport, { useCORS: true } )
                .then((canvas) => {
                    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
                })
    }
```

you could,

```
listingReportToDataUrl().then((listingReportImg  => {
    pdfMake.createPdf(listingReport( listingReportImg )).download('test.pdf')
})
```